# tf.sigmoid() overflow when used for bigger values

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, logistic-regression, sigmoid

I've been trying to make a univariate logistic regression model in python using tensorflow that I learnt in Matlab (ML course on Coursera by Andrew ng). The model converges but only when the initial theta0 nad theta1 variables are defined small(about 1.00) but returns the converging values as nan if initial value is set to 100.00.
Also the same thing happens when learning rate is increased.
The python code is

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
epoch = 100000


x_data = (np.random.rand(100)*100).astype(np.float64)
y_data = np.vectorize(lambda y: 0.00 if y < 50.00 else 1.00)(x_data)

theta0 = tf.Variable(1, dtype=tf.float64)
theta1 = tf.Variable(-1, dtype=tf.float64)

hypothesis = theta0 + (theta1 * x_data)
hypothesis = tf.sigmoid(hypothesis)

term1 = -(y_data * tf.log(hypothesis))
term2 = -((1-y_data) * tf.log(1-hypothesis))

loss = tf.reduce_mean(term1 + term2)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.006).minimize(loss)
init_var = tf.global_variables_initializer()

train_data = []
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_var)
    for i in range(epoch):
        train_data.append(sess.run([optimizer, theta0, theta1, loss])[1:])
        if i%100==0:
            print("Epoch ", i, ":", sess.run([theta0, theta1, loss]))
```

Explanations for the described behavior of code and corrections, or even a better code for above purpose would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: gradient descent optimization methods can be very sensitive to step size and potentially initial values. I'm not familiar with exactly what you are using but trying going for smaller steps size potentially.

Comment: @William yeah I tried using small values of learning rate it does works but not to the best, but still the initial value of thetas messes all up. By the way, can u suggest me any other optimization method?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the issue is. For certain values of theta you're going to get predictions that are wildly wrong. If those values are so wrong that they produce huge errors, it will crash your model. That is why it is better to start at low values for theta (1 or 0). You model simply cannot be that wrong if you have normalized your, so your errors should be manageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` instead of taking the sigmoid and then doing a log to compute the loss. The sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits has some internal logic to help prevent numerical underflow/overflow.